# airodump-ng fopen failed: No such file or directory

Tags: networking, network-manager, aircrack-ng

I was trying to test a wpa wifi network. I wrote the following command

```
airodump-ng -c 11 --bssid 34:5B:34:7B:AC:66 -w /root/Desktop/ mon2
```

Note: The BSSID I have posted here is wrong for of course reasons. And I get the following errors:

```
fopen failed: No such file or directory
Could not create "/root/Desktop/-01.csv"
```

I can clearly see that is there is C language fopen error. Its trying create a csv file. I think mainly for maintaining the passowords it tests. I don't know what is this csv files for just made a guess.

I tried to create a simple .csv file with `C Program` using `fopen` and the `csv` file got created. So, there is not problem with `C env` is guess.

I need  help how do I fix this error?

Comment: -w expects a file prefix, not a directory path, see `man airodump-ng` for details.

Comment: so what's the fix? @mikewhatever

Comment: I don't know much I used this blogpost http://lewiscomputerhowto.blogspot.in/2014/06/how-to-hack-wpawpa2-wi-fi-with-kali.html

Comment: please, either post the code with the problem or remove the `c` tag.

Comment: @user3629249 Removed

Comment: the error message indicates that no file name has been given for the output file.  if the output file is expected to be named `mon2-01.csv` then the space between the path and file name needs to be removed.  Otherwise, supply a valid filename as part of the path parameter

Answer (score 1):

The `-w` parameter of `airodump-ng` is for specifying a file prefix, not a folder.

The right command would be:

```
airodump-ng -c 11 --bssid 34:5B:34:7B:AC:66 -w /root/Desktop/capture_file mon2
```

This will create a file on this path:

```
/root/Desktop/capture_file-01.csv
```

---

**Quote from the `airodump-ng` [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/airodump-ng.8.html):**

> -w , --write 
>       Is the dump file prefix to use. If this option is not given, it will only show data on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your wireless card in monitoring mode

   ```
   airmon-ng start wlan0
   ```
2. Command to listen to the wireless network around you and get details about them

   ```
   airodump-ng mon0
   ```
3. Sniff on channel 6 (-c 3), filtering on a BSSID (–bssid 11:22:33:44:55:66 ), writing the capture to disk (-w capture), using the monitor mode interface (mon0):

   ```
   airodump-ng –w [File name of packet] –c [Target channel no] --bssid BSSID [of target name] mon0
   ```

   (eg: `airodump-ng –w MTNL –c 3 –bssid 11:22:33:44:55:66 mon0`)
4. Using the provided wordlist (`-w /usr/share/wordlists/nmap.lst`), attempt to crack passwords in the capture file

   ```
   aircrack-ng -w wordlist.lst -b 00:11:22:33:44:55 MTNL.cap
   ```

   [ -w=The name of the dictionary file

   -b=The MAC address of the access point

   MTNL.cap=The name of the file that contains the authentication handshake ]

For more details [**click here**](http://www.kalilinuxhack.com/2015/10/hack-wifi-using-kali-linux-20.html)